# Is there "BFU" acronym meaning 'Stupid Average User' (expressively) in English IT slang?

Tags: slang, acronyms

Have you ever encountered given initialism denoting 'Brain-Free User', as opposed to 'power user / geek / nerd / IT professional'?

If so, do you consider its usage 'widespread', at least in your closest circles?

Any archived proof (article, blogpost, discussion, mailgroup) with its occurrence welcomed.

(My research suggests it is common only in a small local community, but to be sure Iʼd like to get qualified feedback.)

Comment: I have never seen it.  There are other expressions such as "operator malfunction" that have some currency, especially in segments of the computer industry involving actual interfacing with (gag) live customers.

Comment: (Might be better asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).)

Comment: The BOFH refers to "lusers."  But that's not restricted to less knowledgable people. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_Operator_From_Hell

Comment: In IT industry and haven't heard of BFU. However, the meaning appears to be related to a similar acronym, PEBCAK (problem exists between chair and keyboard). That, and the "operator malfunction"/operator error example provided above, are probably more common.

Comment: There would be so many fewer excedrin moments in life if all of the PEBCAK, ID10T, BFU, LAMERS and LUSERs out there would just RTFM! The Any Key you need to press? Yeah - it's the one on the case marked "Power" ;-)

Comment: As an aside, BFU is an abbreviation, not an acronym, unless it is pronounced "beefoo" or similar.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error

Comment: We used to call this a "loose connection between the brain and the keyboard".

Answer (score 1):

I have used (and heard used among colleagues) the term **id10t** (pronounced ai-dee-ten-tee) for such people coming from the old slang for a [user error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error). While I don't know if this term is truly widespread, I think that the term "id10t error" *is* widespread enough that most IT insiders would pick up on the meaning right away.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen or heard *BFU* or *brain-free user*, but I might start using them now!

I have heard and used *luser* for the person and *id10t*, *PEBKAC*, *PICNIC*, and *layer 8 error* for their problems.